API running on Azure App Service Plan sleeps even with Always On enabled
I have an API running on an Azure App Service (B1 plan), and have Always On set to On.
The API is accessed via API Management Service. If the API is not accessed for, maybe 5 minutes, it seems to go to sleep, as the next request to it will take up to 30 seconds to return. Subsequent requests respond virtually instantly.
As far as I can tell, it should be a case of simply setting Always On to On, but clearly this isn't the case here.

...have you used the (surprisingly decent) troubleshooting wizards and tools in the Azure Portal to see what they said?  And you say it's running behinf API Management but you haven't told us what happens if you communicate with it directly.

Hi. I've just realised it would help to connect directly, so am giving that a go to see whether it solves the issue. I had not tried the troubleshooting tools, so will give those a go if communicating directly doesn't enlighten further.

It's possible that your application isn't sleeping, but that you have some problem with delayed effects (like a gradual but persistent memory-leak) that causes Azure to kill your running processes - so check your logs.

Since App Service is actually a family of services, you have to edit the question to say clearly which you are using (Windows/Linux/container) and what is the web framework (Java/Go etc.).

Thanks to all who commented. Testing the API outside of API Management Service revealed that the delay was due to API Management Service (Consumption tier) and not the API itself. As I don't need the functionality of the API Management Service at the moment, I'm switching to direct access.
